# Multiple Website with Single Database and Different urls WordPress?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, clone

I was looking to find a solution for making clone websites of my existing WordPress website. the thing is I want to make clones of the website so if one of them will somehow get down the others will be Live. For Example The Piratebay.com they have a lot of clone sites and I you would upload a torrent to one site all of them will have the same torrent available, this is just for example purposes. I want to make a clone of my website so if I add a new post to my any clone website or the original all of the websites will have the same post available on it. For sure they will have their own domain name. The website will use MySql as the form of database. I have searched all over the internet and on StackOverflow as well and couldn't fine a solutuion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same Cloud MySQL database (e.g. Googles Cloud SQL) for all websites. Install wordpress on the first domain and then just copy the wordpress folder to the other destinations (or modify the wordpress-configuration at the other destinations).
Don't use absolute paths for images in your posts etc. (not http://example.com/something/image.jpg).